# no me pasa la condicion de departamento

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo el siguiente codigo en javascript

```
const prompt = require("prompt-sync")({ sigint: true });
var capital;
var departamento;
departamento = prompt("ingrese el departamento: ");

switch (departamento) {
  case "Quindio":
    capital = "Armenia";
    break;
  case "Caldas":
    capital = "Manizales";
    break;
  case "Risaralda":
    capital = "Pereira";
    break;

  default:
  case "":
    break;
}
if (capital != "") {
    console.log("la capital del "+departamento+" es "+capital);
}else{
    console.log("No es un departamento cafetero");
}
```

el problema esta cuando le coloco un departamento distinto de "Armenia" "Manizales" "Caldas"
le coloco "Cundinamarca" me debe salir "No es un departamento cafetero" pero me sale "la capital de cundinamarca es undefined"

Comment: al ojo, tiene que ser `default: break;`, también, cambia `if (capital != "")` por `if (capital)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta de infinit3Loop, es muy buena, dejo dos alternativas a su respuesta, que toman distintos caminos.
Por otro lado me tomé el atrevimiento de modificar el texto que se imprime...

Alternativa "1":

```
switch( departamento ) {
  case "Quindio":
    capital = "Armenia";
      break;
  case "Caldas":
    capital = "Manizales";
      break;
  case "Risaralda":
    capital = "Pereira";
      break;
  case "":
    capital = "";
      break;
  default:
    capital = "";
    console.log( "No es un departamento cafetero" );
      break;
}

if( capital != "" ) {
    console.log( "la capital del departamento de " + departamento + ", es " + capital );
}
```

Alternativa "2":

```
switch( departamento ) {
  case "Quindio":
    set( "Armenia" );
      break;
  case "Caldas":
    set( "Manizales" );
      break;
  case "Risaralda":
    set( "Pereira" );
      break;
  case "":
      break;
  default:
    console.log( "No es un departamento cafetero" );
      break;
}


function set( nombre ) {
    capital = nombre;
    console.log( "la capital del departamento de " + departamento + ", es " + capital );
}
```

Comment: Tenes razon, ahi adapte mi respuesta, muchas gracias.

Comment: :), gracias a ti, entonces borro la mia!!!

Comment: no porque la vas a borrar? déjala ! Si el código es distino al menos da una alternativa

Comment: @infinit3Loop__, tienes razón, tal vez sirva para pensar de otra manera, gracias de nuevo!!

Answer (score 1):

Hace tal que así, aprovecha que devuelve undefined si no concuerda con ningún case del switch y haces un condicional con eso. Otra alternativa es imprimir en cada case y luego usar default pero creo que es mejor así.

```
const prompt = require("prompt-sync")({ sigint: true });
var capital;
var departamento;
departamento = prompt("ingrese el departamento: ");

switch (departamento) {
  case "Quindio":
    capital = "Armenia";
    break;
  case "Caldas":
    capital = "Manizales";
    break;
  case "Risaralda":
    capital = "Pereira";
    break;
}

if (capital !== undefined || capital !== "") console.log("la capital del "+departamento+" es "+capital);
else console.log("No es un departamento cafetero");
```

Comment: Porque el voto negativo?

Comment: Ni siquiera justifican